# rsync backup script fails when options are in variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, rsync, brace-expansion

I want to use rsync for incremental backups. However it fails when I try it like this:

```
SRC="/"
TRG="/backup/"
LNK="/oldbackup/"
OPT="-a --exclude={/dev,/proc,/sys,/tmp,/run,/mnt,/media,/lost+found} --link-dest=$LNK"

rsync $OPT $SRC $TRG
```

But works like this:

```
SRC="/"
TRG="/backup/"
LNK="/oldbackup/"

rsync -a --exclude={/dev,/proc,/sys,/tmp,/run,/mnt,/media,/lost+found} --link-dest=$LNK $SRC $TRG
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Check the order of expansions in `man bash`: brace expansion happens first, variable expansion happens later. Therefore, braces in a variable are not expanded.

You can use an array to capture the values, use expansion already in the assignment:

```
opts=( -a --exclude={/dev,/proc,/sys,/tmp,/run,/mnt,/media,/lost+found} --link-dest="$LNK" )
rsync "${opts[@]}" "$SRC" "$TRG"
```

Comment: Very good.  +1.  For related info,  the OP might want to look at [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)